# Sort Laravel pluck() by value not key?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I've got a form that has a few select elements populated by JSON. It looks something like below.

```
{
    "suppliers":
        {"1":"Amazon","2":"Apple"},
    "manufacturers":
        {"1":"Apple","2":"Lenovo"},
    "categories":
        {"2":"Tablet","3":"Laptop","4":"Desktop"},
    "status":
        {"1":"Ready to Deploy","2":"Deployed","3":"Damaged","4":"Destroyed"}
}
```

How can I sort by value (name) instead of the key (id)? I've tried everything I can think of and I've searched every phrase I can think of, but it's still not sorting alphabetically like I need. Note the orderBy below will sort it in the correct order if viewing the JSON directly in the browser, but in the form my select elements are still ordered by key.

```
public function getFormData()
{
    $suppliers = DB::table('supplier')->orderBy('sup_name','asc')->pluck('sup_name','id');
    $manufacturers = DB::table('manufacturer')->orderBy('man_name','asc')->pluck('man_name','id');
    $categories = DB::table('category')->where('parent_id', 1)->orderBy('cat_name','asc')->pluck('cat_name', 'id');
    $status = DB::table('status')->orderBy('status','asc')->pluck('status', 'id');

    return json_encode(compact('suppliers', 'manufacturers', 'categories', 'status'));
}
```

---

Edit:

Using the following syntax from @Snapey I was able to get the sort order correct

```
public function getFormData()
{
    $suppliers = DB::table('supplier')->orderBy('sup_name','asc')->get(['sup_name','id']);
    $manufacturers = DB::table('manufacturer')->orderBy('man_name','asc')->get(['man_name','id']);
    $categories = DB::table('category')->where('parent_id', 1)->orderBy('cat_name','asc')->get(['cat_name', 'id']);
    $status = DB::table('status')->orderBy('status','asc')->get(['status', 'id']);
    return json_encode(compact('suppliers', 'manufacturers', 'categories', 'status'));
}
```

New output:

```
{
    "suppliers":
        [{"sup_name":"Amazon","id":1},{"sup_name":"Apple","id":2}],
    "manufacturers":
        [{"man_name":"Apple","id":1},{"man_name":"Lenovo","id":2}],
    "categories":
        [{"cat_name":"Desktop","id":4},{"cat_name":"Laptop","id":3},{"cat_name":"Tablet","id":2}],
    "status":
        [{"status":"Damaged","id":3},{"status":"Deployed","id":2},{"status":"Destroyed","id":4},{"status":"Ready to Deploy","id":1}]
}
```

Unfortunately, now I get "object Object" in my select elements and the values are off.

Here's the function that builds my select elements:

```
function refreshData(newId, modalId) { //refreshes select elements on update
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/collection.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(modalId){
            switch(modalId){
                case "supplierModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers, newId);
                    break;
                case "manufacturerModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers, newId);
                    refreshSelect('inputManufacturerModel', data.manufacturers, newId); //modal window select
                    break;
                case "statusModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status, newId);
                    break;
                case "categoryModal":
                    refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories, newId);
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers);
            refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers);
            refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status);
            refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories);
            refreshSelect('inputManufacturerModel', data.manufacturers); //refresh modal window select element
        }
    }
  });
}

function refreshSelect(name, data, newId) {
    // Select by id
    let $elem = $('#' + name);
    // Get current value
    let oldValue = $elem.val();
    // Get option with value 0, which is the first element
    let emptyOption = $elem.children('option').first();
    // Empty the element and add the option. We are back to initial state
    $elem.html(emptyOption);
    // Append elements retrieved from backend
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if(oldValue === key || newId === key){
            $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '" selected="selected">' + value + '</option>');
        }else{
            $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
        }
    });
    if(newId){
      $elem.val(newId);
    }else{
      $elem.val(oldValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your view as well

Comment: Do those Key numbers need to remain the same?  I'm guessing that the client-side code is ordering them according to those numbers.  What if you change those numbers to reflect the new order?

Comment: @AdamWinter yes, they need to stay the same. The client side js is looping over each and building a select list. ```$.each(data, function(key, value) { $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');``` <- the gist.

Comment: Is that key value used in a way that those numbers absolutely have to be associated with  the option?  You can change the client-side script right?  What about this instead:   $.each(data, function(key, value) { $elem.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');

Comment: Seems like you're doing it wrong if the number "4" has to be associated with "Destroyed", but also "Desktop"  Anywhere you have  if(status == '4').....  you could just as well have if (status == 'Destroyed')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the id as a named element rather that using it as the array index. For instance;

```
 $suppliers = DB::table('supplier')->orderBy('sup_name','asc')->get(['sup_name','id']);
```

then in the json you will have an `id` attribute

Edit: for your additional question
something like

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) { 
  if(oldValue === value.id || newId === value.id){ 
    $elem.append('<option value="' + value.id + '" selected="selected">' + value.sup_name + '</option>');
}else{
   $elem.append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.sup_name + '</option>'); } });
```

because now, each item in the array is an object with sup_name and id as attributes

Comment: This is working, thank you. Can you see my edit above? Not sure how to access the proper values in my js as my select now shows ```[object Object]```. I've included the function that builds my selects in my edit.

Comment: Got it! It's working again. Thank you so much for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The following will strip the key numbers out, and just leave you with an array that has your new ordering:

```
public function getFormData()
{
    $suppliers = DB::table('supplier')->orderBy('sup_name','asc')->pluck('sup_name','id');
    $suppliers = array_values($suppliers);
    $manufacturers = DB::table('manufacturer')->orderBy('man_name','asc')->pluck('man_name','id');
    $manufacturers = array_values($manufacturers);
    $categories = DB::table('category')->where('parent_id', 1)->orderBy('cat_name','asc')->pluck('cat_name', 'id');
    $categories = array_values($categories);
    $status = DB::table('status')->orderBy('status','asc')->pluck('status', 'id');
    $status = array_values($status);

    return json_encode(compact('suppliers', 'manufacturers', 'categories', 'status'));
}
```